# Creating a Rails Migration to add a Friendly_id column (which is null) to a table with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, friendly-id

I have a table with data and I would like to add friendly_id.

I don't know how to build my migration as I can't create a table with :null=>false when there's data in it. What I would like to do, was for the migration to run the FriendlyId so it builds the slug and inserts it to the database.

My current Migration is as follows:

```
class AddSlugToSite < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :site, :slug, :string
    change_column_null :site, :slug, false

    add_index :site, :slug, :unique => true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :site, :slug, :string
  end
end
```

And my model:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
end
```

This doesn't work as Rails can't create a field with null=>false when there's already data in there.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to add the column, but do not put the `null:false`.

After that, make a rake task or another migration to populate this column, and only after that, you execute other migration to execute `change_column_null :site, :slug, false`

Or you could do all of that in one migration, but that could be slow:

```
class AddSlugToSite < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :sites, :slug, :string

    Site.where('slug is null').each do |site|
      site.slug = nil # The documentation says this will regenerate the slug
      site.save!
    end

    change_column_null :site, :slug, false

    add_index :sites, :slug, unique: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :sites, :slug, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Indeed, that was my first thought as well. I was just wandering if there was a way to do all of this in the migration :)

Comment: @Tiago I changed the answer to do that. Take a look ;)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did and it worked like a charm! Thanks!